# Set default URL Spring Boot App starts with in deployment

Tags: spring, docker, rest, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot app running on port 5000 with the `server.servlet.context-path=/api`.

When the app starts up, on my machine, I can access the static welcome page (`index.html`) at `http://localhost:5000/api` no problem.

I have this app deployed on AWS CodePipeline in a Docker container.  The problem is that when I access the endpoint of my app at `http://my-api-env.eba-uatdpxjr.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api` it works fine, but I would like to have it so that the root url of my deployment environment doesn't need to have `/api` manually tacked to the end of it to access my service.

**How can I make it so that the deployed app's URL `http://my-api-env.eba-uatdpxjr.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com` automatically includes the app's context path `/api` and renders the static welcome page?**

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY /target/RestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar RestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/RestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "1.0"
services:
  api_service:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

buildspec.yml

```yaml
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - java -version
      - mvn clean package
artifacts:
  files:
    - 'Dockerfile'
    - target/RestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

application.properties

```
# JPA Settings
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

# Configure Port and Context Path
server.port=5000
server.servlet.context-path=/api

# In the master application.properties file we can control which Spring Profile we want to use
spring.profiles.active=dev

# Set Welcome view to index.html page
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .html
```

Answer (score 0):

And why exactly removing the context path (it's `"/"` by default) doesn't work for you?

Comment: That works fine for me but I wanted to know if there was a way to expose the context path by default.